# Numba TypeError: 'output_dir' must be a string or None

Tags: python, jit, numba

I'm trying to work out how to use the Compiling code ahead of time feature of Numba (version 0.28.1+0.gfe99fbc.dirty on Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit) ). I try to run the example code from the documentation:

```
from numba.pycc import CC
import numpy as np
cc = CC('my_module')
# Uncomment the following line to print out the compilation steps
#cc.verbose = True

@cc.export('centdiff_1d', 'f8[:](f8[:], f8)')
def centdiff_1d(u, dx):
    D = np.empty_like(u)
    D[0] = 0
    D[-1] = 0
    for i in range(1, len(D) - 1):
        D[i] = (u[i+1] - 2 * u[i] + u[i-1]) / dx**2
    return D

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

But it gives an Error message ending with:

```
/projects/py/numba$ python derivatives.py 
In file included from /home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/pycc/modulemixin.c:16:0:
/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/pycc/../_helperlib.c: In function ‘import_cython_function’:
/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/pycc/../_helperlib.c:555:42: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyMapping_GetItemString’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
     cobj = PyMapping_GetItemString(capi, function_name);
                                          ^
In file included from /home/ohm/anaconda2/include/python2.7/Python.h:133:0,
                 from /home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/pycc/../_pymodule.h:6,
                 from /home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/pycc/modulemixin.c:8:
/home/ohm/anaconda2/include/python2.7/abstract.h:1356:29: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
      PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyMapping_GetItemString(PyObject *o, char *key);
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I put your code in a file called `foo.py` and then ran `python foo.py` from the command line and it worked fine. I got a few compiler warnings, but that was it. I'm using the same version of Numba as you are on OSX. How did you run your script?

Comment: I ran it now as you did, and got a different error message. Before I was running it from within Spyder.